# cURL POST to HttpClient

Tags: c#, http, curl, post, httpclient

I have the following link provided by an API, which should be used to get an authentication token:

```
curl -d "client=YourAppName&accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&service=reader&Email=test@krasnoukhov.com&Passwd=..." https://theoldreader.com/accounts/ClientLogin
```

When I enter enter this line into linux console (with my own credentials obviously) I get the expected result:

```
SID=none
LSID=none
Auth=AnyKindOfKey12345
```

But I need to use this in C#, so therefore I tried using the HttpClient class as following:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
string url = "https://theoldreader.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
string request = "client=YourAppName&accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&service=reader&Email=test@krasnoukhov.com&Passwd=...";
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(request));
```

But I get status code "403 - Forbidden" everytime. What am I missing?
I tried setting the encoding of StringContent to UTF-8 or ASCII, but no change.

Comment: By default `-d` in curl will send data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but you are using plan text (`StringContent`) with `HttpClient`. Use `FormUrlEncodedContent` instead of `StringContent` adding each parameter as a single `KeyValuePair`.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying something like this? I don't think the way you currently doing it is the correct way.

```
        string url = "https://theoldreader.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var urlData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client", "YourAppName"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("accountType", "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("service", "reader"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Email", "test@krasnoukhov.com"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Passwd", "pancakes")
        };

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(urlData) };

        var res = await client.SendAsync(request);
```